# interpolation with matlab function griddata

Tags: image, matlab, grid, interpolation

If I have four images of the same scene with known subpixel shift between them, and i want to interpolate these four images on a high resolution grid using matlab function `griddata`

see the following figure: The four images are the green,gray,black circles and the white triangles
[image]

I have a problem with the first,second and third argument of the `griddata` function

```
output = griddata(X,Y,Z,[1:numberOfHrColumns],[1:numberOfHrRows]','cubic');
```

What should be the values of X,Y,Z?

Is there any other matlab function can make this interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `griddata` since your source is on a regular grid, just [`interp2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html).

The syntax of `interp2` is similar to `griddata`:

```
 Vq = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)
```

The first two arguments (`X` and `Y`) are the grid coordinates of the source data, and the third (`V`) is the corresponding data points.  The high resolution grid is specified by `Xq` and `Yq`.

Comment: does `interp2` can interpolate four images, i think it only interpolate one image. How can i define `X` and `Y` of all images using `meshgrid`

Comment: You run it for each image.  `meshgrid` is straightforward, usually like `[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:numCols,1:numRows);`.

Comment: OK, and after run `interp2` for each image, the final image is the sum?

Comment: @HforHesham No, you run it on each image, getting a new image for each one.  Then it is up to you to do the sum.  If they are the same size, then it is simply a mean of the images (A+B+...)/n. Are your images RGB or grayscale?

Comment: @HforHesham Then you can do `I(:,:,ii) = interp2(...)` where `ii` is the image index, followed by `Imean = mean(I,3);` to average the images.

Comment: Another question: How to define the `X` and `Y` for a shifted image? is this right:
`[X,Y]=meshgrid([1-shift_in_x:2:2*numberOfLRColumns-shift_in_x],[1-shift_in_y:2:2*-numberOfLRRows-shift_in_y]);`

Comment: @HforHesham You can go either way: Have the shift built into `X` and `Y`, OR have `X` and `Y` be `[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:numCols,1:numRows);` and shift the other way with `Xq` and `Yq` containing the shift.  Try them out and see if the results are as expected.  Experiment with large shifts to see which way the output image is shifting. Defining `X` and `Y` with a simple `meshgrid` of integer-valued indexes of each pixel, and interpolating at shifted points defined in `Xq` and `Yq` is probably the intuitive way to go.

Comment: @chappjc What exactly is the difference between `griddata()` and `interp2()`? They seem to do exactly the same thing.